# How do I view the achievement guide?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft on PS4, I want to view the achievement guide (the map where it shows different things you should accomplish such as baking a cake, etc.), but I have no idea how to open that menu.

Is this possible on PS4? If so, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Tap on your avatar on the bottom left corner, and then you just scroll down to view achievements.